# Why are ids of different elements of array.array identical?

Tags: python, arrays

I ran into some confusion when using `array.array` in Python. Here's the code:

```
import array

a = array.array('l', [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])

for e in range(4):
    print(a[e], id(a[e]))
```

and the results confused me:

```
1000 140505536637552
2000 140505536637488
3000 140505536637552
4000 140505536637488
```

Why does `a[0]` have the same id as `a[2]`? I use Python 3.7.

-----------Supplement--------------
As @Mad Physicist suggests, here is the result of printing `id(a[e])` twice:

```
for e in range(4):
    print(a[e], id(a[e]), id(a[e]))

1000 139949448301712 139949448301712
2000 139949448299920 139949448299920
3000 139949448301136 139949448301136
4000 139949448301712 139949448301712
```

I take that this is due to the GC and memory management mechanism.

Comment: For me 1 and 3 is the same `id`, and so 0 and 2.

Comment: @U9-Forward Yeah, I'm the same, see the results. I just wonder why.

Comment: Probably because they are uncached integers which coincidentally get allocated into the same bit of memory. Just guessing though.

Comment: Remember that an array is not a list. `a[e]` actually has to create a new integer object. What happens when you try to print `id(a[e])` twice in a row for the same `e`?

Comment: The python document said "`id(obj)` Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value". I guess the lifetime of `a[e]` is over after every iteration in the for loop.